# Hide option in a select box dependant on previous choices. Options generated from SQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html-select

I would like my user to be able to select the people they went hiking with. I have used JScript that allows the user to add more Selection boxes depending on how many people were on the hike. The names in this selection box are generated from a database query.

I would like to put something in place that would stop the same person being selected multiple times from different selection boxes. For example if option 1 in selected in the first section box, it should not be available to the user in the 2nd, 3rd, 4th.....selection box.

The selection boxes are generated using the following code

```
<TABLE id="buddyTable" class="form" border="1">
            <TR>
                <td><input type="checkbox" required="required" name="chk[]" checked="checked" /></td>
                <TD><label>Buddy</label>
                <select name="buddy[]">
                    <option>Solo</option>
                <?php

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                // output data of each row
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo '<option value = "'.$row["idPerson"].'">'.$row["Forename"]. ' '.$row["Surname"].'</option>';
                //echo "name: " .$row["Forename"]. " " . $row["Surname"]. "<br>";
                }
            } 
            else {
                echo "0 results";
            }               
            $conn->close();
            ?>
                </select>
                </TD>
            </TR>
            </TABLE>
```

The JScript to allow more selection boxes to be added is here

```
function addRowBuddy(tableID) {
var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
if(rowCount < 10){                          // limit the user from creating fields more than your limits
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
    for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
    }
}else{
     alert("Maximum number of buddies is 10.");

}
```

}

I have looked for a few solutions and although they are good, none of them inform me on how to do this when MySQL/php is also involved.

Any hints, suggestions or guides would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hide `<option>` is not supported cross browser. Choices are disable or remove/replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind using a framework, you could use w2ui's enum field (Multi Select):

http://w2ui.com/web/docs/form/fields-enum

The items array for the field can be either pulled directly from an url or it can be a predefined array.

It would also save you the hassle of creating more selection boxes as you could select all persons in one field.

Or maybe you could use http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/

Comment: I like the look of this and could really clean up my project. Thank you for the suggestion. 

I'd still accept advice based on my original question while I look into this alternative.

Answer (score 0):

@David please find my solution here - [http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GqRWQe]

**Note:** Since this post has been tagged under jQuery, I have used jQuery 1.10.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <TABLE id="buddyTable" class="form" border="1">
            <TR>
                <td><input type="checkbox" required="required" name="chk[]" checked="checked" /></td>
                <TD><label>Buddy</label>
                    <select name="buddy[]" class="buddies">
                        <option class="default">Select</option>
                        <option value="solo">Solo</option>
                        <option value="user1">user1</option>
                        <option value="user2">user2</option>
                        <option value="user3">user3</option>
                        <option value="user4">user4</option>
                    </select>
                </TD>
            </TR>
        </TABLE>
        <button type="button" onclick="addRowBuddy('buddyTable');">Add Buddy</button>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.js"></script>
        <script>
            var selectedPersons = [];       
            // add rows copied first row as reference
            function addRowBuddy(tableID) {
                var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
                var rowCount = table.rows.length;
                if(rowCount < 10){                          // limit the user from creating fields more than your limits
                    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
                    var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
                    for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
                        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
                        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
                    }
                }else{
                    alert("Maximum number of buddies is 10.");
                }
                $(row).find('.buddies').change();
            }

            // disable other buddies from getting selected
            function disableAlreadySelectedUsers(tableID) {
                var otherOptions = 'option[value="'+selectedPersons.join('"],option[value="')+'"]';
                $('.buddies').each(function() {
                    var thisVal = $(this).val();        
                    $(this).find('option').not(otherOptions).removeAttr('disabled');
                    $(this).find(otherOptions).not('option[value="'+thisVal+'"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                });
            }

            // lets get all the buddies selected from all the select boxes available
            function getSelectedValues() {
                selectedPersons = [];
                $('.buddies').each(function() {
                    if(($(this).val()).toLowerCase() != 'select') {
                        selectedPersons.push($(this).val());
                    }
                });
            }
        
            // updates the selection on every select box change
            $('#buddyTable').on('change', '.buddies', function() {
                getSelectedValues();
                disableAlreadySelectedUsers('buddyTable');
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```